# Proving if f is a smooth function, then f(x) is a Taylor Series.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, taylor-expansion, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let f be a smooth function. Let R denote the radius of convergence of the Taylor series, centered at a, of f. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $M_n = \sup \{|f^{(n)} (t)|: t \in \mathbb{R} \}$. 
$$
\mbox{If}\quad\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{M_n}{n!} R^{n} < \infty
\quad\mbox{then}\quad
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)} (a)}{n!} (x-a)^n \forall x \in (a - R, a + R)
$$

A hint was given saying to show that
$$\mbox{if}\quad x \in (a - R, a + R)
\quad\mbox{then}\quad
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{M_n}{n!} (x-a)^n = 0
$$

Edit: I think I just figured out why the hint is helpful. Below is my proposed proof. A corollary to Taylor's theorem says that the error term is bounded by:

$|f(x) - \sum \frac{1}{n!} f^{n} (c) (x-c)^n \leq | \frac{|x-c|}{(k+1)!} \sup | f(t)^{k+1}|$

So I'm guessing that if we show that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{M_n}{n!}R^{n}=0$, then we're just left with $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)} (a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$, which would exist by definition since f is a smooth function (n times differentiable for all $\mathbb{R}$). But I'm still not sure how I'm supposed to prove the hint.

EDIT: Ok, I know that if $\sum \frac{M_n}{n!} (x-a)^n = 0$, then $\lim \frac{M_n}{n!} (x-a)^n=0$. So I'm thinking of using the radius of convergence of power series theorem. And so I know that we will have convergence if $|x-a| < \underline{\lim} ( \frac{M_n}{n!} )^{1/n}$. I have no idea on how to prove this, or if this is even the correct method. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why use $\mathbb R$ for the radius of convergence?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. This was a condition listed in the question itself.

Comment: @zhw. My bad! I've corrected the answer. The radius of convergence was supposed to be an abritrary R, not $\mathbb{R}$